# How to deploy a tomcat application with https using Letsencrypt

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, lets-encrypt

Client requirement is to deploy a WAR file in tomcat which has to work and to be secured with SSL by using Letsencrypy.

Currently i'm having a subdomain which is pointed to the linux CentOS Hosting server which i'm holding the root credentials. 
ex: IP: 75.87.88.98
Subdomain: beta.domain.com

My tomcat is currently running on following URL: http://beta.domain.com:8080
How can i use Letsencrypy to deploy my tomcat application and get the URL like this : https://beta.domain.com

Comment: what is actually the problem? what have you tried?

Comment: I had installed apache webserver and installed Letsencrypt to tie up with Apache, Now my subdomain of Apache default webpage is loading with https://beta.domain.com.